# How do I add time sourced from an external source as an X axis to a ChartJS graph?

Tags: javascript, time, chart.js

https://plnkr.co/edit/O4BxVsdOZBc4R68p

```
fetch(target)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    var prices = data['Time Series (5min)'];
    for (prop in prices) {
      var stockPrices = prices[prop]['1. open'];
      //change to 2. high, etc
      console.log(`${prop} : ${stockPrices}`);
      stocksData.datasets[0].data.push({x: prop, y: +stockPrices})
      //time x axes are preventing render
      window.lineChart.update();
    }
  })
```

I am getting information from the AlphaVantage API and am trying to graph the time as the X axis and the open price as the Y axis.  However, the time from the API is in an odd format and doesn't appear to graph.  I have looked into Moment.js but that appears to be making times, not formatting them.  Can anyone give me any pointers on graphing the time correct?

Comment: I added an answer with a working code. It wasn't the date format the real problem apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from 2 things:

1. Your Chart config in options with `xAxes` that should be `xAxis` instead
2. Missing Labels and correct data in Chart data

Here is the codes that works:

```
var stocksData = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'open',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(104,0,255,0.1)',
      data: [

      ],
    },
  ],
};
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

  var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: stocksData,
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxis: [
          {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
  window.lineChart = lineChart;
};

var sym = 'AAPL'; //get from form
var tseries = 'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY'; //get from form
var target = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=${tseries}&symbol=${sym}&interval=5min&apikey=VA3RZ8B9PPYWKQKN`;
function update () {
fetch(target)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    var prices = data['Time Series (5min)'];
    for (prop in prices) {
      var stockPrices = prices[prop]['1. open'];
      //change to 2. high, etc
      console.log(`${prop} : ${stockPrices}`);
      //stocksData.datasets[0].data.push({x: prop, y: +stockPrices})
      stocksData.datasets[0].data.push(stockPrices);
      // Format date here. For example with Moment:
      // var date = moment(prop).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      stocksData.labels.push(prop);
      //time x axes are preventing render
      window.lineChart.update();
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

A complete format for Chart data would be like:

```
var stocksData = {
  labels: ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date4'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'open',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(104,0,255,0.1)',
      data: [
        'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Then each data and date label should be push separately:

```
stocksData.datasets[0].data.push(stockPrices);
stocksData.labels.push(prop);
```

To format with Moment you can use:

```
var dateStr = moment(prop).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: @Aaron just make sure you change `xAxes` to `xAxis` not to break the display, and you can tune it up as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The "odd" time format is ([almost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)) the standard [international datetime format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). In this case `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I strongly suggest you familiarise yourself with it and use it in preference to `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`.

You can fix your code by changing the x-axis type to `time` and adding the appropriate [configuration options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html):

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        type: 'time',
        ...
```

Note that you'll also need to change your call to Chart.js to the [version with moment.js bundled](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#selecting-the-correct-build) (or include moment separately):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Thanks for helping!  I'll try both of u guys' answers.